# Google Maps with multiple markers in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to display a Google map in a Bootstrap modal with multiple markers. I have found several posts where people were having problems displaying the map on the modal with just one marker, but none with multiple markers. This is what I currently have, but my map is just showing up gray.

```
var locations = [...]

var complexMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('complexes-modal-map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

//create empty LatLngBounds object
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        icon: locations[i][3],
        map: complexMap
    });

    //extend the bounds to include each marker's position
    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(complexMap, marker);
         }
     })(marker, i));
 }

$("#complexes-modal-map-canvas").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    var currentCenter = complexMap.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(complexMap, "resize");
    complexMap.setCenter(currentCenter);
    complexMap.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

Comment: can u priovide a "working" sample which reproduces the issue (live-snippet/fiddle/bootply)?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things I had to do to make this work. The first thing was an obvious mistake - I was selecting the incorrect element on the "shown.bs.modal" method. I needed to select my Bootstrap modal, not the Google Map. The second thing was to call the "fitBounds" method before calling the "resize" event and setting the center.

```
$("#complexes-modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    complexMap.fitBounds(bounds);
    var currentCenter = complexMap.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(complexMap, "resize");
    complexMap.setCenter(currentCenter);
});
```